# Creating a list from returning values of varius types

Tags: java, list

I have a class with different fields.

```
public class Temporary
{
   private Integer id;
   private String name;
   private String value;

public Integer getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getValue() {
      return value;
   }

   public void setValue(String value) {
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

I am creating a a test, and I am getting stuck on creating a list, I need to make a list and I am not sure how.

Here is my test

```
@Test
   public void samepleList() throws Exception {

      Temporary temp = new Temporary();
      temp.setId(42);
      temp.setName("a");
      temp.setValue("b");
      temp.setId(36);
      temp.setName("c");
      temp.setValue("d");
      temp.setId(42);
      temp.setName("e");
      temp.setValue("f");

      List<Temporary> sampleList = Lists.newArrayList();
      sampleList.add(temp.getId();
      sampleList.add(temp.getName();
      sampleList.add(temp.getValue();

}
```

My error occurs at the sampleList.add(get.getId), as it says

The method add(Temporary) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Integer).

How would I fix it and be able to put them into a list

Comment: You're using **encapsulation** and then abandoning it. What's the point of creating a `Temporary` object, if you're going to store the value of its fields in the `List`?

Comment: sampleList.add(temp.getId() **)** ;

Comment: Does `private Integer id;` need to be `Integer`? can it not just be an `int` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add Temporary objects to a `List<Temporary>`, not ints or Strings, or whatnots. You need to re-read on generics and on Java collections.

Incidentally, this makes no sense:

```
  Temporary temp = new Temporary(); 
  temp.setId(42);
  temp.setName("a");
  temp.setValue("b");
  temp.setId(36);
  temp.setName("c");
  temp.setValue("d");
  temp.setId(42);
  temp.setName("e");
  temp.setValue("f");
```

Why create a Temporary object and then set fields only to over-write the fields later? This whole thing smells funny.

Perhaps instead you want to do:

```
List<Temporary> tempList = new ArrayList<>(); // create list

Temporary temp = new Temporary();  // create Temporary object
temp.setId(42);
temp.setName("a");
temp.setValue("b");
tempList.add(temp);  // add it to the list

temp = new Temporary();  // create new Temporary object
temp.setId(36);
temp.setName("c");
temp.setValue("d");
tempList.add(temp);  // add it to the list

temp = new Temporary();  // create new Temporary object
temp.setId(42);
temp.setName("e");
temp.setValue("f");
tempList.add(temp);  // add it to the list
```

Answer (score 1):

Your list can contain only Temporary object

```
  List<Temporary> sampleList = Lists.newArrayList();
      sampleList.add(temp);
```

later `get` that `temp`. It contains all of your values. Like

```
Temporary getttingTemp = sampleList.get(0); // 0 is index
Integet myIdIsBack = getttingTemp.getId(); // Yippe, got it
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a specific type to the list instead of `Temporary` objects, you need to change your list declaration to have that specific type, for example if you want to add integers:

```
List<Integer> sampleList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

You can't declare a list to take some specific type and then pass it different types. Unless you specify`Object` as the type (which can be a bad idea)

Otherwise if you want to add `Temporary` objects and keep your list declaration as it is, you need:

```
sampleList.add(temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared sampleList  as `List<Temporary>` so you are allowed to add only `Temporary` object to sampleList .

```
 List<Temporary> sampleList = Lists.newArrayList();
 sampleList.add(temp);
```

You can iterate list as follows.

```
   for (Temporary t: sampleList ) {
        System.out.println(t.getId());
        System.out.println(t.getName());
        System.out.println(t.getValue());
   }
```